# using facebook sdk to login to app

Tags: android, facebook

**Update**

I used Session class as told. But still, i dont think its working. below is my code:

But still, my edittext is not updated with name. it is showing You are not logged in. Neither any of the log messages in the Session.CallBack method are shown in my logcat

```
public class profile extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView profilePropic;
EditText name;
Dialog dialog;
Button gallery;
Bitmap bmp;
FileOutputStream fos;
LoginButton loginButton;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    profilePropic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_propic);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {
                name.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
            } else {
                name.setText("You are not logged");
            }
        }
    });
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
        }
    }
};


private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
    new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = Crop.getOutput(result);
        Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(profilePropic);
        try {
            bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("ProPic", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);


    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("ProPic");
        Bitmap bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        profilePropic.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void changeAvatar(View view) {
    // Intent pickFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // startActivityForResult(pickFromGallery, OpenGallery);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.propic_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Show us how you look like !");
    dialog.show();
    gallery = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        beginCrop(data.getData());
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == gallery) {
        Crop.pickImage(this);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public boolean checkPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null) {
        return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    } else
        return false;
}

public void requestPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null)
        s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, PERMISSIONS));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
  }
}
```

I haver researched on this tipic for quite a while.

What I came across is that in many tutorials

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook(App_Id);
```

is used while in many other sites, it is said that Facebook class is now deprecated. In facebook developers page also, Session class is used. What is that and how to use that?

This is my first app. If any one guide me with complete detail about this concept, it will be greatful for me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS CLASS SHOULD BE CONSIDERED DEPRECATED.

All public members of this class are intentionally deprecated. New code should instead use Session to manage session state, Request to make API requests, and WebDialog to make dialog requests.

Adding @Deprecated to this class causes warnings in other deprecated classes that reference this one. That is the only reason this entire class is not deprecated.

Read below document regarding deprecation :-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Facebook/

Update your sdk of facebook from below link :-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading

Comment: i used Session class, but still have some problems I updated my question. Plz have a look